# for the query of methods of rotation

Tags: iphone

I have 1 UIViewController.

in that i wrote,

```
- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
   NSLog(@"A");
} in UIViewController.

- (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation
{
    NSLog(@"b");
}
```

but this method is not called
why is it so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to do two things:

1. Tell device to track orientation changes: call `[[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];`
2. Implement your View controllers `-shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation` method - return YES for orientations you want to support.